DISM shows good - Cannot update AV/Patch
Not sure what's broken but for the last few weeks i've been unable to patch or update the protection on a Windows 11 machine.
DISM shows good. SFC shows good.
Windows Update error is
Some update files are missing or have problems. We'll try to download the update again later. Error code: (0x80070003)
Images attached to showDISM Log
Patch error

Your DISM log is incomplete. I can’t help with a screenshot of a partial segment of the log.
